# Blank identifier in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

In golang there is the `_` (Blank Identifier).

```
myValue, _, _ := myFunction()
```

this way you can omit the 2nd and 3rd return values of a function.

In javascript is it possible to do this?

```
function myFunction() {
   return [1,2,3]
}

// Something like this
const [first, _, _] = myFunction()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When destructuring, unused items can be removed *completely* (no need to specify a variable name that won't be used later), and unused trailing array items don't even need commas (have the array `]` end at the final destructured item you need):

```js
function myFunction() {
   return [1,2,3]
}

const [first] = myFunction()
const [, second] = myFunction()
const [,, third] = myFunction()

console.log(first, second, third);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who google brings here. For all I could find JS doesn't have a mechanism for blank function arguments.
like `foo(one, two, three)` becoming `foo(_, _, three)` if `one` and `two` are not used in the function.

There is `foo({}, {}, three)`.

Apparently everything can be an anonymous object. But I don't know if it is 100% side effect free.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).